Aes.CreateDecryptor.TransformFinalBlock throws an error The input data is not a complete block
Hi I am struggling with encyption / decryption.
My encryption happens here like this:
private static string CreateRequestVerificationToken()
{
    var key = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptionKey"];
    
    var unprotectedData = string.Format("{0}|{1}", "A", "B");
    var src = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unprotectedData);
    
    using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 128;
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        aes.GenerateIV();
    
        using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
        {
            var crypted = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(crypted);
        }
    }   
}

On the other side the decryption goe like this:
private static string DecryptData(byte[] protectedData)
{
    var key = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptionKey"];

    using var aes = Aes.Create();
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.KeySize = 128;
    aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    aes.GenerateIV();

    using ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    byte[] decryptedText = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(protectedData, 0, protectedData.Length);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedText);
}

At the line decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(protectedData, 0, protectedData.Length); I am getting the following error:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The input data is not a complete block. at System.Security.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoDecryptor.UncheckedTransformFinalBlock(ReadOnlySpan1 inputBuffer, Span1 outputBuffer) at System.Security.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoDecryptor.UncheckedTransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount) at System.Security.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)

When decrypting, the IV of the encryption must be used. This is not the case with your code: When decrypting, a random IV is generated (aes.GenerateIV()). Use the IV of the encryption (the IV is not secret and is passed to the decrypting side along with the ciphertext, usually concatenated).

In addition, the ciphertext must not be UTF8 encoded, as this corrupts the data. If the ciphertext is to be converted into a string, a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 must be used. Before decryption, the data must be Base64 decoded.

You should also consider PKCS#7 padding (more reliable than Zero padding) and a key derivation function like PBKDF2 (more secure if the key material is a string). Note that the block size and key size do not have to be set explicitly: The block size for AES is by definition 128 bits, the key size is set implicitly when the key is set.
